# How can I tell if a webproperty is deleted using Google AnalyticsService?

Tags: c#, google-api, google-analytics-api

I am using the Google Analytics Api to get [web property information](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/analytics/v3/analytics.management.webproperties.list) from my Analytics account.

When I log into analaytics though, I only have one website, but through the api I get several (old and deleted sites)

My code is like this:

```
        var provider = new WebServerClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description)
                           {
                               ClientIdentifier = _appId,
                               ClientSecret = _appSecret
                           };

        var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<WebServerClient>(provider, x => new AuthorizationState { AccessToken = token });
        var analyticsService = new AnalyticsService(auth);

        var accounts = analyticsService.Management.Accounts.List().Fetch();

        foreach (var account in accounts.Items)
        {
            var webProperties = analyticsService.Management.Webproperties.List(account.Id).Fetch();

            // todo: determine if web property is still in use?
        }
```

From code how can I tell which ones are still active?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a bit more digging.

It seems there is no flag or anything like that indicating it has been removed, but if you keep digging into the result set you will notice that at the profile level, a profile that doesn't have child items seems to be a deleted one.

Which makes sense I guess there wouldn't be a profile associated with those that have been removed.

```
var provider = new WebServerClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description)
                           {
                               ClientIdentifier = _appId,
                               ClientSecret = _appSecret
                           };

        var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<WebServerClient>(provider, x => new AuthorizationState { AccessToken = token });
        var analyticsService = new AnalyticsService(auth);

        var accounts = analyticsService.Management.Accounts.List().Fetch();
        var result = new List<Profile>();

        foreach (var account in accounts.Items)
        {
            var webProperties = analyticsService.Management.Webproperties.List(account.Id).Fetch();

            foreach (var webProperty in webProperties.Items)
            {
                var profiles = analyticsService.Management.Profiles.List(account.Id, webProperty.Id).Fetch();

                if (profiles.Items != null && profiles.Items.Any())
                {
                    // these are the ones we want
                    result.AddRange(profiles.Items);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```